# Cannot install tensor flow using command pip install tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, pip

I am getting following errors :
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow-2.0.0.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

When i go to the folder using terminal i cannot see any file named tensorflow-2.0.0.dist-info.

pip command i am using is pip install tensorflow .

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/08/1ff15637a03b1565dd6cb0916b3ca6873db3a1fc69be0ed851be936e5633/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: gast==0.2.2 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.16.5)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.weakref>=1.0rc1; python_version < "3.4" in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.0.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.1 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.6.1 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mock>=2.0.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-applications>=1.0.8 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow) (0.30.0)
Requirement already satisfied: functools32>=3.2.3 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.2.3.post2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.7.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.6 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34>=1.1.6; python_version < "3.4" in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: astor>=0.6.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: futures>=2.2.0; python_version < "3.2" in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from grpcio>=1.8.6->tensorflow) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=41.0.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow) (41.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: funcsigs>=1; python_version < "3.3" in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from mock>=2.0.0->tensorflow) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from keras-applications>=1.0.8->tensorflow) (2.10.0)
Installing collected packages: tensorflow
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow-2.0.0.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Comment: could you please add a pip command that you use?

Comment: @Faran2007 pip install tensorflow

Comment: full traceback?

Comment: I want  have some file which can run with scipy and TensorFlow corresponding to python 2.7 .

Comment: could you please give me the full traceback

Comment: @Faran2007 How to know full traceback  ?  please tell then i will check and tell you

Comment: Try `pip install tensorflow --user`

Comment: @tdurnford he already did that but it doesn't work

Comment: @HarryWilliamson copy all errors in terminal/console

Comment: @tdurnford i am getting ERROR: Invalid requirement: '\xe2\x80\x94user'

Comment: @Faran2007 edited , please  check

Comment: it is your Operating System that doesn't allow it

Comment: @Faran2007 This means i cannot install Tensorflow on ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like access problem. Which platform are you using, is it Ubuntu, Windows, MacOS etc.?

I assume it is MacOS or Ubuntu, try using `sudo pip install tensorflow`

Comment: I am using Ubuntu

Comment: It is giving error ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main```

Comment: Okay, then it looks like `pip's` problem, follow this command in [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599#issuecomment-414157896) issue.